# UV Map a logo on an object not showing right

Tags: uv

I'm just starting out in blender, and I am making a monster energy drink can.  And on the tab, which is it's own object I want to place a monster logo on it.

[image]

So Here are the steps I took.. but where have I gone wrong?

Made a seam...
[image]

I selected all the inner faces of seam, pressed U and UNWRAP

[image]

I added the image to the UV editor screen.

[image]

This is what the node editor looks like for the pop tab

[image]

So now I resized the mapping in the UV editor
[image]

So I went into texture mode and got out of edit mode. Still no results.
[image]

Material mode looks like this
[image]

So the goal is to keep the green color I have applied to it, but just to add that logo on top..  cant figure this out for the life of me... Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your material doesn't include the texture map at all.  You need to mix it in somehow.  Here's an example where I'm using an image with a solid color:

[image]

You need to use the UV coordinates as the vector for a Texture Map, which you'd set to the Monster logo.  Then, mix it with the green color and use that for your diffuse.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Still not showing.. hmm?

Comment: If I could upload a screenshot I would!

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I didnt have a line plugged in to the mix node!

Comment: no problem!  Glad to help!